# How to determine whether a variable is unsigned or not in ANSI C

Tags: c

I am learning "Expert C Programming" by Peter Van Der Linden. In chapter A.6, the writter described how to determine whether a variable is unsigned or not in K&R C.The macro is below:

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (a>=0 && ~a>=0)
```

The book is very old, it was first published in 1994! And I have not learned K&R C before.
The question is that how to determine whether a variable is unsigned or not in ANSI C.

I have tried to solve the problem like this. Since "0" is int in ANSI C, and any other number except float, double and long double will be converted to int or unsigned int by Integer Upgrade when compare with 0. So I want to find an edge between unsigned and signed number. When I compare (the edge type)0 with a, the type of a will not be changed. The macro also the model is below:

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (a>=(the edge type)0 && ~a>=(the edge type)0)
```

I can not find the edge type, is there anybody can help me solve the problem?
I have changed "number" to "variable" for more accurate expression.

Comment: You have to find out whether the signed bit is set or not, that's the idea.

Comment: Why do you need such a macro? I don't see any uses for it. (And I'm curious.)

Comment: A *number* is not *usigned*, it can be *positive* or *negative*. A *type*, on the other hand, can be signed or unsigned (which, I assume, is what your question is about). Anyway, the code will not work for things like `unsigned char`, as `~a` will be converted to an `int`.

Comment: @Tony: an integer variable *can* be signed or unsigned. If it is unsigned, setting the highest bit will **not** make it negative.

Comment: @Mat - It's a helper macro. It lets you test (in another, more complicated macro) whether a given argument is of a signed or unsigned type, which can be very important. It facilitates generic programming with the C preprocessor.

Comment: @Lindydancer:How do you know ~a will convert unsigned char to int?

Comment: That macro cannot be used to determine whether a variable is declared as signed/or unsigned. Nor can it determine whether the value is positive or negative, because the ~ operator will integer promote 'a'. Further, if 'a' is unsigned, balancing will make '0' unsigned too, and a comparison between anything unsigned > 0U is pointless (always true). All of it suggests that your book is focusing on weird, irrelevant things, and that it possibly teaches dangerous practice too.

Comment: @JACK It is required to do so by the _integer promotion rules_ of the C language. (Google it)

Comment: @JACK, in C, all operations are conceptually performed in the type `int` or larger. For most operations, this is of more academic nature, but it can bite you for ~. A classical gotcha that will fail is testing if all bits in an `unsigned char` value is set by `~x == 0`, as `~x` will be promoted to an integer, it will set all the high bits making the comparison fail.

Comment: "The book is very old, it was first published in 1994!"  Damn!  Now I'm depressed...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### How this works

A signed variable has to store its sign in *some* bit. Usually this is the most significant one, but it could be any of them. An unsigned variable has no sign bits; thus, the lowest value it can hold is 0. This means that for an unsigned variable `a`, the expression `a >= 0` will *always* be true.

So we have:

```
( a >= 0 && ~a >= 0 )
```

If `a` is unsigned, the first is true (it has to be), and the second is true (because whatever value `~a` is, it's still an unsigned value, so it's still `>= 0`). If `a` is signed, that means that if the sign bit is set, `a >= 0` is false (and the expression returns false, stating that this variable has a signed type). If the sign bit isn't set in `a`, then when `~a` inverts *all* the bits in `a`, the sign bit (whichever one it is) *has* to be set. This means that it has to be a negative number, which means that `~a >= 0` returns false.

This does rely on the standard integer promotions to work like you'd expect them to.

### How it doesn't work

```
unsigned char x = 1; // or whatever

printf("%s\n", ISUNSIGNED(x) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"); // prints "FALSE"
```

As someone else pointed out, `unsigned char` gets promoted to an `int` since any value of `~a` for an `unsigned char a` can easily fit in the range of an `int`. This is arguably a failing in the standard integer promotions (or a failing in the typing of integral literals).

There might be another implementation of `ISUNSIGNED` or `ISSIGNED` somewhere that can overcome this limitation. The [P99 macro library](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/) has some mind-bending uses of macros, many relying on C99's variadic macros, but unfortunately the macro to check whether an expression is signed or not (`#define SIGNED(expr) ((1 ? -1 : expr) < (1 ? 0 : expr))`) succumbs to the same integer promotions. This might be the best you can do (though I suppose it's better than nothing in the cases where you'll want it).

Comment: It also won't work on unsigned short nor C99 bool type. Together with char these are the "small integer types" and all of them are subject to the integer promotions.

Comment: `P99_SIGNED(expr)` boils down to `(typeof(expr)) -1 < ((typeof(expr)) 0` where it uses a clever trick to avoid actually calling `typeof` (it does something like this `1 ? -1 : expr` to get a `-1` in the type of `expr`, check the [`P99_PROMOTE_M1`](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/p99__int_8h_source.html#l00375) macro).

Comment: @user786653 - I just finished editing that in, but thanks. Glad people are keeping me on my toes.

Comment: @Chris Lutz:Excellent work!Thank you.And thank you for all the people helping me to solve the problem.

Comment: @user786653, @Chris, in fact if the type is "small" (=promoted to `int`) the P99 macros only work if it is a standard data type, by using tricks with `sizeof`. Theoretically, if `a` would be of some small extended integer type this would fail.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

A signed long/int/short/char is negative if the MSB is set.
An unsigned long/int/short/char is NOT negative if the MSB is set.
In tabular form:

```
          MSB=0  MSB=1
unsigned  +      +
signed    +      -
```

The answer therefore is: signedness is an *interpretation*. The same number (sequence of bytes) can be interpreted as signed or unsigned; you can't decide if a number is signed or not by inspecting its value/contents. That's what static typing is (also) for.

note: in the comments it was mentioned that C probably doesn't mandate the MSB to be the "sign" for signed integer types. This is almost always true, though.

note2: the original formulation of the question asked about determining the signedness of a *number*, not of a *variable* (hence my answer about interpretation and static typing in C)

Comment: MSB indicating +/- likely assumes a "2's complement machine architecture".  And C isn't hardwired to this type of signed number represenation.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations  On the flip side, I do not know of a modern computer that isn't 2's complement.  But I bet someone can quote a good story about some existing mainframes still around...

Comment: Being pedantic I don't think the C standard guarantees that the sign bit is the MSB (though it probably always is in practice). Ref: [§6.2.6.2.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: Then I guess my answer still holds, i.e. "you can't (let alone portably)"

Comment: I have found some information in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit

Comment: I think you're mistaken: some bytes in memory, yes, signedness is an interpretation. If you're passed a `void*` pointing to those bytes, there's nothing you can do to determine what type it was written as. However, in C every value has a type, it is more than just bytes. So if you have a integer value (or an expression) then it *is* either of signed type or unsigned type. Telling which in a macro is the tricky part.

Comment: @Steve: The question originally asked if it was possible to determine the signedness of a _number_, not of a _variable_. For the original formulation of the question, my answer was and still is correct.

Answer (score 4):

`#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (a>=0 && ((a=~a)>=0 ? (a=~a, 1) : (a=~a, 0)))`

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the only answer proposed here that works with types smaller than int too.  It's worth noting that the trick is to force `~a` to work on its original type by storing it back inside `a`.  The drawback is that `a` must be an lvalue, but it's fine for my use case :-)

Comment: If `a` can be a C99 `_Bool`, the macro above fails by changing the value stored in `a`.  For this case, here is another macro to try before: `#define ISBOOL(a) (a == 0 ? ((a=2)==1 ? (a=0,1) : (a=0,0)) : (a == 1 && ((a=2)==1 ? (a=1,1) : (a=1,0))))`

Answer (score 2):

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(type) (((type)-1) >= 0)
```

or

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (((typeof(a))-1) >= 0) // This is a GNU extension
```

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question. This presents an implementation that works for a given type (with no explanation as to why it works), whereas the question asks for an explanation of one that works for a given variable.

Comment: Since `-1` is not representable by unsigned types, I didn't feel like it needed an exponation. The main problem is that we need a cast to the type we need, which cannot be achieved in ANSI C if we only have the variable name in arguments.

Comment: @Chris: I agree. It would work with a variable, however, if compiler supports the nonstandard `typeof` extension.

Comment: There's a way to write `isunsigned(var)` without nonstandard expressions.

Comment: Shouldn't you have said (in the first `#define`) `(((type)0)-1 >= 0)`? I mean, what is `type-1`?! Now `(type)0-1` makes more sense

Comment: Say type is `unsigned int`, then `((type)-1)` is `((unsigned int)-1)`, which is a cast. It gives some big number > 0.

Comment: The second expression seems to meet my need.I use Linux to program.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this question but not restricted to C89  (technically C11 is also ANSI C because ANSI has ratified it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ISSIGNED(x) _Generic((x), \
    unsigned char: 0,       \
    unsigned short: 0,      \
    unsigned int: 0,        \
    unsigned long: 0,       \
    unsigned long long: 0,  \
    signed char: 1,         \
    signed short: 1,        \
    signed int: 1,          \
    signed long: 1,         \
    signed long long: 1,    \
    char: (CHAR_MIN < 0)    \
)

int main()
{
    char x;
    printf("%d\n", ISSIGNED(x));
}
```